# How to find "enter" key event functions in games

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to locate the function that handles the Enter key press event from a dialog box in a very simple game (no directx afaik, game has a spashscreen that says "Made with Macromedia"). I think I've found the WndProc function (by xrefing RegisterClass calls and looking at the struct argument), but when I set a breakpoint at the top of the WndProc function, its never getting triggered?

Any tips? thanks

Comment: Sounds like the game is written in Shockwave/Flash. Have you tried decompiling it with a tool like [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)?

Answer (score 1):

[JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/)  Is an another great SWF decompiler. It will show you the actionscript code of the game file which will help you understand the logic of the game.